# pdfkit not rendering the pdf from html properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, pdfkit

I've installed pdfkit and everything seems to be working fine. However, the PDF doesn't look quite like the page i'm trying to have rendered as a PDF. I've tried to make sure that the css files are being loaded properly but I'm not sure how to confirm that. I loaded them inline on the view and also tried specifying the pathname for the pdf object. FYI i'm using bootstrap.

However, all elements on the page are pretty much pulled all the way to the left of the page. I also tried adding %i.icon-user to test if that asset is loading on the pdf and it doesn't. but i'm not sure if that means the css isn't loading or not.

Lastly, I'm using fluid design (responsive) completely for the view, could that be causing the issue?

here's the controller for the view i'm loading:

```
  def client_view
    @invoice = Invoice.find_by_public_id(params[:public_id])
    kit = PDFKit.new(render_to_string(:client_view, :layout => false))
    kit.stylesheets << Rails.application.assets['application.css'].pathname
    kit.to_file("#{@invoice.public_id}.pdf")
  end
```

Comment: I tried PDFkit with Bootstrap, and it was a frustrating experience.
It was unreliable, and would crash the web server a lot.
I gave up, and decided to put in the extra work and use Prawn.
It was well worth the effort. I'm pretty sure PDFkit doesn't work well with CSS media queries. [Bootstrap Responsive Design](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Comment: I haven't deployed to heroku yet so i haven't run into web server issues. Were you able to get the pdfs looking correct or no? Also, how did you get prawn working with html=>pdf generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Turns out, PDFkit wasn't playing nicely with pre-compiled assets. Since I was just pointing PDFkit to the assets pipeline folder, it wasn't rendering the assets. So, I precompiled them (locally) and linked the PDFkit object to the locally rendered css file and everything looks great now (even with responsive design). However, I haven't pushed to heroku yet so I'm not sure how that's going to react.